# Ember - Trigger "mouseEnter / mouseLeave" only for view parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to trigger mouseEnter and mouseLeave for a view, specifically only the `<li>` element which contains children. The code below seems to add an event on the `<li>` and it's children, which typically does not return the `<li>`, usually a `<p>` or `<img>`.

How can I target just the `<li>` that is created by the view?

**My view:**

```
App.MediaView.Gallery.Item = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    mouseEnter: function(e) {
        var $this = $(e.target);

        if ($this.is('li')) {
            this.toggleDetails('show', $this);
        }
    },

    mouseLeave: function(e) {
        var $this = $(e.target);

        if ($this.is('li')) {
            this.toggleDetails('hide', $this);
        }
    },

    toggleDetails: function(which, $this) {
        console.log(which);
        console.log($this);
        console.log('------------------');
    }
});
```

**My template:**

```
<ul>

        {{#each content}}
            {{#view App.MediaView.Gallery.Item}}
                <div name="content" {{bindAttr class="size type"}}>

                    {{#if isImage}}
                        <img {{bindAttr src="content"}} alt="Title" />
                    {{else}}
                        <p>This is a video</p>
                    {{/if}}

                    <div class="vignette">
                        <div class="actions">
                            <a href="#" class="download">Download</a>
                            {{#if isImage}}<a href="#" class="enlarge">Enlarge</a>{{/if}}
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            {{/view}}
        {{/each}}

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically to the get the DOM element created by the view you can use `this.$()` this get's you a jQuery object for the view's element.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Created [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/evinay/2/edit) to illustrate this. As you can see it is only getting the text of an element inside the li that is hovered over (in the console).

Comment: Holy crap. I was completely over thinking it. Thank you!